# How can I find the index of a character in a string in Rust?

Tags: string, indexing, rust, character

I have a string with the value "Program", and I want to find the index of character 'g' in that string.

Comment: There are different kinds of indices into a String, because there are a number of levels at which you can count. Counting bytes gives the byte index (byte where a character starts), counting graphemes gives a grapheme index, counting code points gives a code point index.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are looking for the `find` method for String.  To find the index of `'g'` in `"Program"` you can do

```
"Program".find('g')
```

[Docs on find](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find).

Comment: Be careful, it's not the correct answer since `"πx".find("x")` returns byte index `2` not char index `1`!

Answer (score 63):

Although a little more convoluted than I would like, another solution is to use the [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) iterator and its `position()` function:

```
"Program".chars().position(|c| c == 'g').unwrap()
```

[`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) used in the accepted solution returns the *byte offset* and not necessarily the index of the character. It works fine with basic ASCII strings, such as the one in the question, and while it will return a value when used with multi-byte Unicode strings, treating the resulting value as a character index will cause problems.

This works:

```
let my_string = "Program";
let g_index = my_string.find("g");   // 3
let g: String = my_string.chars().skip(g_index).take(1).collect();
assert_eq!("g", g);   // g is "g"
```

This does not work:

```
let my_string = "プログラマーズ";
let g_index = my_string.find("グ");    // 6
let g: String = my_string.chars().skip(g_index).take(1).collect();
assert_eq!("グ", g);    // g is "ズ"
```

Comment: Find returns the starting byte index, so it should not be used as a character index. So instead of using it with `chars().skip()`, it should be used to slice: `let g: String = my_string[g_index..].chars().take(1).collect();` and that works fine no matter what kind of characters you use.

Answer (score 4):

If your word has several `g`'s you could use `enumerate` to find all indices:

```
"ඞggregate"
    .chars()
    .enumerate()
    .filter(|(_, c)| *c == 'g')
    .map(|(i, _)| i)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();  // [1, 2, 5]
```

If the string contains ASCII characters only:

```
"aggregate"
    .bytes()
    .enumerate()
    .filter(|(_, b)| *b == b'g')
    .map(|(i, _)| i)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();  // [1, 2, 5]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=af531683332b8e74485f2984db2e863a)